# Refactor xpath from many parents

Tags: ruby, xpath

I am trying to get a value using xpath and my code is like this:

```
path = "//league/match/odds/type[@name='1x2']/bookmaker[1]"
    @a = xml.xpath(path).map do |x|
      {country => x.parent.parent.parent.parent['country']}
end
```

Example of simplified version of xml file:

```
<league country="england">
<match>
<home alternate_id="5363803833" id="2341073" name="Leicester"/>
<away alternate_id="5363803814" id="2340835" name="Arsenal"/>
<odds>
<type name="1x2">
<bookmaker id="779" name="10Bet">
<odd name="1" value="4.15"/>
<odd name="2" value="1.87"/>
<odd name="X" value="3.80"/>
</bookmaker>
<bookmaker id="947" name="12Bet">
<odd name="1" value="3.90"/>
<odd name="2" value="1.87"/>
<odd name="X" value="3.60"/>
</bookmaker>
</type>
</odds>
</match>
</league>
```

Is there a better way to replace `parent.parent.parent.parent` ? Thanks

Comment: Can you please show example of XML?

Comment: yup need your HTML code to help you

Comment: Alright thanks...a simple version of the xml file added!

Comment: @pyfl88 what result do you want to get from that xml/html?
Aslo please correct you XML, so we can test/play with it (some tags are not closed properly).

Comment: @DmytroPastovenskyi added a more detailed version. I am trying to get value of country from the xml file. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
/league/@country
```

Will return a country. That is what you just asked.